# How can I map responseEntity to custom class in java

Tags: java, json, resttemplate, dcm4che

I have a service returns a list of something like this as responseEntity

```
{
    00080005={vr=CS, Value=[ISO_IR 100]},
    00080054={vr=AE, Value=[DCM4CHEE]}, 
    00080056={vr=CS, Value=[ONLINE]}
}
```

How can I create a custom class mapping this, and is this way better or using responseEntity ?

-- note that I have an error when using responseEnttiy said

```
Can not deserialize instance of javax.json.Json out of START_ARRAY token
```

Comment: The code you showed doesn't look like JSON at all. Properties would be `"key": "value"`, where you seem to use `=` and don't quote the key.

Comment: It's json+dicom, response put Content-Type as json+dicom

Comment: I don't know that format, but a quick Google search shows [this page](https://www.dicomstandard.org/dicomweb/dicom-json-format) and the samples on there look quite different from what you posted. My suspicion is that you already parsed it (possibly automagically via some framework) into some domain objects and what you post above is the `toString()` output of those domain objects. Again: what you posted **is not JSON**.

Comment: Ok, actually I'm parsing it manually now, but I will take a look at this link, thanks

Answer (score -1):

your service return as JSON formatted ?

i have similar condition when develop some project...but i'm not quite sure your service return is a json formatted..

i've use Jackson for mapper and Gson Library for jsonobject. every request i map to entity  using jackson.

```
JsonObject gson         =   new Gson().fromJson(stringJson, JsonObject.class);

//--YA--Menggunakan ObjectMapper untuk convert string json ke entity
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Token token         = new Token();

//--YA-- setting jackson untuk bypass error jika terdapat body yg tidak bisa di map 
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); 
//--YA-- setting jackson untuk abaikan case sensitive
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true); 

token   = mapper.readValue(gson.toString(), Token.class);
```